# The Owlcarousel showing was showing error in angular

Tags: angular

I used `Owlcarousel` in my website. It showing below error while running the project

ERROR in src/app/templates/home/home.component.ts(13,21):

> error TS2339: Property 'owlCarousel' does not exist on type
>   'JQuery'

Comment: How you including Owlcarousel in angular component file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i thinks you have little inclusion issue, you have to follow bellow step :

**1/** you have to require `jQuery` and `owlCarousel` by npm import in index.ts for example or from external ressource.

**2/** on your directive or component add this line in top of your file :
`declare var $:any;` this will prevent any jQuery typing issue.

**3/** use your `owlCarousel` plugin as regular usage from `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook. Is because you have to wait HTML rendering before initialize your carousel.

`$(this.sliderElement.nativeElement).owlCarousel();`

`$('.mySelector').owlCarousel();`

Live sample :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-caroussel-angular?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts